# Want to convert pdf image created using "matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages" package to byte array

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, data-science, visualization

I am using "matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf" package to create pdf and to store the plot created using matplotlib. But, apart from saving the pdf image in my repository, I want to return a byte array of this pdf. (Note: I don't want to read the pdf file and convert it to byte array).

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1 = np.arange(10)
y1 = x1**2

x2 = np.arange(20)
y2 = x2**2

pp = PdfPages('test.pdf')


def function_plot(X,Y):
    plt.figure()
    plt.clf()

    plt.plot(X,Y)
    plt.title('y vs x')
    plt.xlabel('x axis', fontsize = 13)
    plt.ylabel('y axis', fontsize = 13)
    pp.savefig()

function_plot(x1,y1)
function_plot(x2,y2)

pp.close()
```

Comment: If you don't want to read the PDF file, then what do you want?  You can't recreate the input data that produced the PDF.  What are you going to do with this "byte array"?

Comment: I want to return this byte array as a response of api request.

Comment: If I am deploying this changes in dev environment, then this created pdf file is of no use.

Comment: Check the documentation.  `PdfPages` accepts a file-like object, so you can open an `io.bytesio` fake file and have it write there.